# Probability question Vicotorian england

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-distribution

In Victorian England, the probability of a child born being male was 0.512.
In a family of 10 children, find the probability that

- exactly 6 boys
- There were no boys
- There were more girls than boys

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! This looks like a problem on the binomial distribution. What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I just dont know how to do it. Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please can anybody help me solve it?

Comment: As already mentioned... this should (*with the appropriate assumptions*) be a *trivial example* of the binomial distribution.  Surely... you should have seen dozens of other examples of the binomial distribution at this point.  If you haven't, well... searching wikipedia for [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) should give you all the information you could want and more including an example.  Searching google in general will give you hundreds if not thousands more pages, each with their own examples.

Comment: Traditionally, $n$ in the formulas will refer to the number of total trials... here $n=10$.  $p$ will traditionally refer to the "probability of success"... here "success" meaning "is male" and we have $p=0.512$.  Now... the probability of exactly $k$ successes in $n$ trials where trials are independent and each have success with probability $p$ will be $$\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$ which for your first part of the problem you have $n=10,p=0.512$ and $k=6$... For the other parts... try thinking about what adding probabilities does...

Comment: Feel free to update your question with what you think the solution should be or what you have tried and what exactly it is that you do not understand. We will be happy to guide you further.

Answer (score 0):

If you have never taken and are not taking, a basic probability course, where in the world did you get this question?  You need to know that is a given event has probability p of happening then the probability of it happening n times is a row is p multiplied by itself n times: p^n.

The probability of it NOT happening is 1- p and the probability if it happening n times in a row, then not happening m times in a row, in that order, is p^n(1-p)^m.

The probability of it happening n times and not happening m times in any specific order, is also p^n(1-p)^m.

The probability of it happening n times and not happening m times in any order is that probability times the number of different possible orders of m+ n things, m the same, and n the same, is the "binomial coefficient, $\begin{pmatrix}n+ m// n\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}m+ m \\ m\end{pmatrix}= \frac{(n+m)!}{n!m!}$. So the probability of it happening n times and not happening m times in any order is $\frac{(n+m)!}{n!m!}p^n(1-p)^m$.